# Django: save() method in a different database

Tags: python, django, save, using

I'm trying to save an object in a non-default database. I have already configured a second connection.

I know that in order to get objects it is `Class.objects.using('the_db').all`

But when I try `object.using('the_db').save()` it doesn't work. (Error: "object has no attribute 'using'".
I also tried `object.save('the_db')` but it also does not work.

How can I achieve this? I couldn't find the correct syntax.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try `object.save(using='the_db')`

Relative django documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#moving-an-object-from-one-database-to-another